# How to write testcase for embedded kafka in springboot application using junit

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit5, embedded-kafka

i don't know How to write testcase for **embedded kafka** in **springboot** application using **junit mockito** i refer some code and i used that but **KafkaEmbedded KafkaEmbedded**  is *deprecated*

```
 @TestConfiguration
        @EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, controlledShutdown = false,
        brokerProperties = {"listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:3333", "port=3333"})
        public class KafkaTestConfig {
            @Autowired
             KafkaEmbedded kafkaEmbeded;
            @Autowired
            KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;
            @Before
            public void setUp() throws Exception {
              for (MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers()) {
                ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(messageListenerContainer, 
                kafkaEmbeded.getPartitionsPerTopic());
              }
            }
            @Bean
            public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
                return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(kafkaEmbeded));
            }
            @Bean
            public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
                KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
                return kafkaTemplate;
               }
             }
```

Comment: what problem you are facing when writing tests?

Comment: Thanks,i updated my query check it out and please help me to resolve this issue